# How to pass in a customizable html string to mouseover in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a class function that will add a d3 circle. In the 'mouseover' callback function, I'd like to pass in the HTML based on the id and name of the object.

```
add(svg, x, y) {
    svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bubbles")
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100)
            .on("mouseover", showTooltip)
            .on("mousemove", moveTooltip)
            .on("mouseleave", hideTooltip)

showTooltip () {
    tooltip
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
    tooltip
        .style("opacity", 1)
        **.html("I want to add a custom html based on this.id and this.name")**
        .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+30) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]+30) + "px")
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#selection_html, try something like this: selection.html((d) => doSomthing(d));